# Disable multiple checkboxes with javascript

Tags: php, javascript

I've got a problem with my JS function. I'll explain that to you with my code and a Prt Sc.

Code = http://jsfiddle.net/dKeRf/

This is a Php function and JS function.

Screen = http://img824.imageshack.us/i/antoe.png/

If one of the 2 checkbox over the table is checked, all the checkbox in the two table must be disabled. For the moment It works for the first checkbox, but not for the second, and I ask you why ? :)

I use '10' in my 'For' jut for a test, I'll change that latter by the number of row of the table.

Thanks for your help and have a good day !

Comment: Paste code right here instead of external sources. And remember to clear its syntax because no one likes to read messy code.

Answer (score 1):

Add a class to all of the checkboxes:

```
<input class="the_checkbox" id='{unique_id}' name='module[]' type='checkbox' value='{unqiue_value}'>
<input class="the_checkbox" id='{unique_id}' name='module[]' type='checkbox' value='{unqiue_value}'>
<input class="the_checkbox" id='{unique_id}' name='module[]' type='checkbox' value='{unqiue_value}'>
<input class="the_checkbox" id='{unique_id}' name='module[]' type='checkbox' value='{unqiue_value}'>
```

Then use jquery to update all of the checkboxes at once:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".selectAll").click(function() {
        if($(".selectAll").attr("checked")) {
            $(".the_checkbox:checkbox").attr("disabled", true);
        } else {
            $(".the_checkbox:checkbox").removeAttr("disabled");
        }
    });        
});
</script>
```

**UPDATE:** Changes the answer to use the .class name for updating the checkboxes instead of the ID so that the ID can remain unique and conform to HTML standards.

Comment: Thanks for your answer !

But the checkbox can't have the same id, it doesn't work. 

i'll try to use jQuery, that'll maybe help me.

I'll also clean my code and post it.

Comment: I'm not certain what you mean by "It doesn't work" with all the same ID. Is there something else you are doing with the ID that requires them to all be different? If not, it will work. I have tested it, so I know it will work with all the same ID. Follow my example above. Give the checkbox that disables all other checkboxes the class of selectAll (class="selectAll") and give the checkboxes that need to be disabled the ID of cpt2 (id="cpt2") and use the jquery code I posted and it will work.

Comment: I would really suggest against this. According to the HTML spec, ids are required to be unique. Although yes, JQuery will still work, document.getElementById() will not. And if you ever want to learn JavaScript and free yourself from dependance on JQuery, you will need document.getElementById().

Comment: Thanks for the education. I didn't even realize this about the ID. I have seen so many tutorials on using the ID the way I described, I assumed it was correct.

Comment: I have updated my answer. You can now remove the down vote. ;)

Comment: :) Yes, classname is much better.

Comment: I said " It doesn't work " because if the checkboxes have the same ID, getElementById() still not work. 

Thanks for your help guys !

Answer (score 1):

IDs are not allowed to start with a number, they must start with a letter. So `document.getElementById(1234)` will fail (I think IE might not say anything and allow it, but FF doesn't work). You should be ok with just putting a letter in front of the number and change the getElementById to `document.getElementById('cb'+id2);`.

Also, just a side note, if you are passing in `this` to a function `onClick`, that parameter is a reference to the element that was clicked. So there is no need to get `box.id` and then do `document.getElementById(checkId)`. technically `document.getElementById(checkId)` is === `box` so you could just say `box.checked`.

http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/types.html#h-6.2. This is the spec that talks about ID attribute naming requirements:

> ID and NAME tokens must begin with a letter ([A-Za-z]) and may be followed by any number of letters, digits ([0-9]), hyphens ("-"), underscores ("_"), colons (":"), and periods (".").

**Edit:**

Even better than using `document.getElementById()` to select each checkbox, would be to use `document.getElementById()` on a parent element that the checkboxes you want to disable share (such as the table they are in) and then use `document.getElementsByTagName('input')` to get a collection of all the checkboxes and loop/disable them with that. So the JS disable code would look like:

Some table:

```
<input type='checkbox' onClick='checkCBs(this,"someTable1");'>
<table id='someTable1'>
  <tr>
    <td>This is checkbox 1:</td>
    <td><input type='checkbox' name='group1' value='checkbox1'></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>This is checkbox 2:</td>
    <td><input type='checkbox' name='group1' value='checkbox2'></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

The code:

```
function checkCBs(box, parent){
    var parent = document.getElementById(parent),
        CBs = parent.getElementsByTagName('input'),
        i;
    //loop through all input elements
    for(i=0;i<CBs.length;i++){
        //make sure the input is a checkbox
        if(CBs[i].type && CBs[i].type=='checkbox'){
            //set disabled on this checkbox to opposite
            //of whether box is checked.
            CBs[i].disabled = !box.checked;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: That seems to be the beginning of an elegant solution. Is there anyway to eliminate the for loop? If not, at least for better performance (although it may be small), the CBs.length should be a set var before the for loop so you do not have to call the 'length' function for each iteration in the loop.

Comment: correct, the CBs.length should be set before the loop, I was just being lazy. As for the `for` loop, it is required. There isn't a way in DOM to affect multiple elements in a collection/object/array without looping through them and affecting each individual value. Even in JQuery, you invoke it with one function call, but it will still loop through those elements and affect each one individually. You could write a function to do it for you (same thing as using jquery) but there probably isn't a much of a benefit.

Comment: Thanks for your help Jonathan, cdburgess and afuzzyllama, i'll try Jonathan's solution to solve my problem !

parent.getElementsByTagName seems to be a very good way to do that. Thank you !